# How to append and prepend double escape to a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I have a string eg. `Here is a (TEST)`, I need to convert it to `Here is a \\(TEST)\\`

I tried using `str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")`
but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Is it enough to .replace("(", "\\\\(") and the same for the closing paren?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var str = "(TEST)";
str = str.replace("(", "\\\\(").replace(")", ")\\\\");
alert(str);
</script>
```

Try something like this

Answer (score 2):

This solves your problem:

```
var str = "Here is a (TEST)";
str = str.replace("(", "\\\\(");
str = str.replace(")", ")\\\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something this can be done using:

```
'Here is a (TEST)'.replace(/([(){}\[\]])/g, '\\\\$1');
//=> "Here is a \\(TEST\\)"
```

Comment: This isn't quite right though. \\ is on the wrong side of the closing paren.

Comment: I suspect OP's example isn't right but I will wait for OP's comments.

Comment: My bad, I've reverted it :)